# Calling method on dynamic Class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How do I formulate

```
[NSClassFromString(classname) myMethod:param1 more:param2];
```

such that the compiler does not give a warning saying that +myMethod may not be implemented ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[NSClassFromString(classname) performSelector: @selector(myMethod:more:) withObject:param1 withObject:param2];
```

Answer (score 6):

Quick & dirty: cast the return of `NSClassFromString` to `id`, if myMethod:more: is unique. The method binding doesn't happen until runtime, so the correct impl will be called.

Slightly cleaner: use NSObject's `-(id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject withObject:(id)anotherObject`, if param1 and param2 are `id`s. It works for class methods too when called on a class object.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you have multiple arguments, you can’t use `-performSelector:withObject:`. You’ll have to use what Objective-C uses under the hood, `objc_msgSend()`. But first you’ll have to cast it. Here’s how:

In your implementation file (`.m`), add the line `#import <objc/message.h>` to the top. Then, you need to cast `objc_msgSend()` appropriately. In this example, we’ll assume that `param1` and `param2` are Objective-C objects and that `-myMethod:more:` returns `void`.

```
void (*myMsgSend)(id self, SEL _cmd, id param1, id param2);
myMsgSend = (void(*)(id, SEL, id, id))objc_msgSend;
```

Once you’ve cast it appropriately, call your new function:

```
myMsgSend(obj, @selector(myMethod:more:), param1, param2);
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, first line declares variable `myMsgSend` which is pointer to a function with `(id self, SEL _cmd, id param1, id param2)` arguments ?

Answer (score -1):

Try typecasting the value returned by `NSClassFromString()` to `id` first.

Comment: The type returned from `NSClassFromString()` is generic and messageable.

Comment: `NSClassFromString()` return value is of type `Class`, the compiler will warn about calling anything not defined in Class. id is generic, and will make the compiler happy.